# How many integration tests (or scenarios) should I write for each feature?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, bdd, acceptance-testing

I am looking at a project now that has both unit tests and integration tests (using BDD).

The integration tests use one file of values for every test. (Given that there are almost unlimited permutations of sets of data.) I am trying to figure out if this is OK and why. (I am very new to "testing".)

Am I right in saying that these integration tests are meant to test that the data flows correctly through the components, so it's OK to only have one set of values?

And that the "permutations" of data should be tested in the unit tests? So then we know that the individual units can handle different data.

Or have I completely missed a trick?

Comment: "its ok to only have one set of values" that would depend on the software in question; there can be no universal answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, testing only one set of data is very minimal. Probably it is just one scenario of good weather behavior.

I suggest also to add bad weather behavior.

For about permutations: this can easily get out of hand. Therefor, google on MC/DC coverage: Modified Condition Decision coverage. It reduces the maximum number of all possibilities while having still the same coverage on that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

In BDD integration tests have two purposes:

- You write integration tests to test-drive (to force you to implement so that the tests pass) the major areas of your application's behavior. The integration tests are a specification, a means of communication between developers and stakeholders, and between developers and future developers.
- Secondarily, integration tests do what you said: they test that each interaction between unit-tested components is correct.

If you develop test-first you'll usually find that test-driving motivates all of the integration tests you need, but if you write some code before tests you may need to go back and write more integration tests so you have enough integration coverage. In that case you should try to reverse-engineer the business reason you wrote that code and express it in an integration test that shows value to the business.

Whether "one set of values" is enough for a given integration test depends on the business meaning of each possible set of values. For example, if you're processing a check, you might want three integration tests:

- one in which the check is for less than the available funds and the payment succeeds
- one in which the check is for more than the available funds and the account becomes overdrawn
- one in which the check is somehow invalid and there is an error.

You'd use unit tests to drive minor variations in those scenarios, e.g. different error scenarios (one where the amount on the check is zero, one where it's illegible, and one where it's not from the right bank) which all result in showing an error on the screen.

P.S.: "integration test" means different things in different contexts, but I went with your terminology. I suppose that by "integration test" you mean something like a Cucumber scenario, with the emphasis on it being a piece of specification rather than on the technical details of how the test works.